# xcode keeps crashing on startup without reason

Tags: xcode

Can anyone please help me fixing my xcode? 
Whenever i try to start xcode it crashes see report:

```
Process:               Xcode [705]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               7.3.1 (10188.1)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-10188001000000000~3
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       817226719
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [705]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2016-05-25 16:53:24.034 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.4 (15E65)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        D02DE49B-6ABC-FC9A-09FD-60215D357133


Time Awake Since Boot: 67 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        1  Dispatch queue: DVTFilePathEventWatcher - event queue

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000101e33000-0000000101e37000 [   16K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 7D1014

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff97d09fba lstat$INODE64 + 10
1   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff96f1ba37 _NSFileExistsAtPath + 200
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff96f1b871 -[NSFileManager fileExistsAtPath:] + 127
3   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x0000000101f65841 +[DVTPlatform _propertyDictionaryForPlatformAtPath:] + 136
4   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x0000000101f656c1 -[DVTPlatform initWithPath:] + 427
5   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x0000000101f65a6e +[DVTPlatform _loadPlatformAtPath:] + 65
6   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x0000000101f6615a __46+[DVTPlatform loadAllPlatformsReturningError:]_block_invoke + 1221
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9154240b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff91542303 dispatch_once_f + 67
9   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x0000000101f65c8c +[DVTPlatform loadAllPlatformsReturningError:] + 283
10  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x0000000102b3fc8a IDEInitialize + 372
11  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000103457336 -[IDEApplicationController _applicationWillFinishLaunching:] + 702
12  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000103456e22 -[IDEApplicationController applicationWillFinishLaunching:] + 141
13  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9ba9dbbc __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
14  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9ba9db4f ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 63
15  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9ba9dac7 _CFXRegistrationPost + 407
16  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9ba9d832 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 50
17  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9ba5a5e2 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1922
18  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9ba59835 _CFXNotificationPost + 693
19  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff96f1cfda -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
20  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010202cadf -[NSNotificationCenter(DVTNSNotificationCenterAdditions) _dvt_postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 831
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff908e917e -[NSApplication finishLaunching] + 354
22  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010259b1d4 -[DVTApplication finishLaunching] + 296
23  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff908e8cc1 -[NSApplication run] + 231
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff908b246c NSApplicationMain + 1176
25  com.apple.dt.Xcode              0x0000000101e3439b 0x101e33000 + 5019
26  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff916b15ad start + 1

Thread 1 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: DVTFilePathEventWatcher - event queue
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9ba281e9 CFArrayGetCount + 25
1   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x0000000101f24e3b -[DVTFilePathEventWatcher _setupStream] + 667
2   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x0000000101f25369 -[DVTFilePathEventWatcher _resetStream] + 116
3   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x0000000101f24a07 __41-[DVTFilePathEventWatcher watchFilePath:]_block_invoke + 1111
4   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x00000001020b5667 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 293
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9154d93d _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9154240b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9154703b _dispatch_queue_drain + 754
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9154d707 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 549
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9154240b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9154629b _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1890
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff91545b00 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff948f64de _pthread_wqthread + 1129
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff948f4341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff97d09efa kevent_qos + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff91548165 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 216
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff91547dcd _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff97d095e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff948f6578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff948f4341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff97d095e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff948f6578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff948f4341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff97d095e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff948f6578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff948f4341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 1 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000001  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x0000000000000030  rdx: 0x0000060000000600
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x00007fff9be5da60  rbp: 0x0000700000080940  rsp: 0x0000700000080930
   r8: 0x0000000000000040   r9: 0x00007fff79e331e0  r10: 0x00007fff9e609901  r11: 0x00007fff9ba281d0
  r12: 0x00007fff924934c0  r13: 0x0000000000000002  r14: 0x00007fff924934c0  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x00007fff9ba281e9  rfl: 0x0000000000010246  cr2: 0x0000000102120177

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000154
Trap Number:     133


Binary Images:( I SKIPPED THE BINARY IMAGES )


External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 1
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 6066
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=373.9M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=373.9M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=61.1M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=61.1M(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Activity Tracing                  2048K        2 
CG shared images                   144K        5 
CoreUI image file                  128K        2 
Dispatch continuations            8192K        2 
Foundation                           4K        2 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        3 
MALLOC                            38.4M       19 
MALLOC guard page                   32K        7 
Process Corpse Info               2048K        2 
STACK GUARD                       56.0M        7 
Stack                             10.1M        7 
VM_ALLOCATE                         40K        6 
__DATA                            36.2M      311 
__IMAGE                            528K        2 
__LINKEDIT                       106.6M       30 
__TEXT                           267.4M      302 
__UNICODE                          552K        2 
mapped file                       32.0M        5 
shared memory                      324K        8 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                            560.4M      705 

Model: MacBookPro12,1, BootROM MBP121.0167.B16, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2,7 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.28f7
Graphics: Intel Iris Graphics 6100, Intel Iris Graphics 6100, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x483943434E4E4E424C54414C41522D4E5544
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x483943434E4E4E424C54414C41522D4E5544
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x133), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.95.175.1a6)
Bluetooth: Version 4.4.4f4 17685, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0256G, 251 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 27.1
```

I tried reinstalling xcode and rebooting etc. 
Anyway i think it has something to do with xcode pointing to a wrong memory location..

Comment: Delete derived data folder and try

Comment: Have you got any plugins installed that could be forcing Xcode to crash?